# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 when submitting a form

Tags: php, mysql, session

I've been fighting with a bit of code for a week now, not seeing what the heck is wrong...

I have a gaming site I'm trying to build new character sheets for, the form is all done, the action pointing to another page that is strictly the sql for inserting the information into the database.  We have good connection, but it is hanging at the second insert statement.  The code was working previously, but we had to delete the database and rebuild it, resulting in a rebuild of the insert sql lines.

The first portion of the insert code is:

```
if($_POST['Submit']=="Submit")
{
$sql="INSERT INTO accounts (log_name,owner,account_type,date_joined) VALUES (\"$_POST[char_name]\",\"$_SESSION[logname]\",\"$_POST[account_type]\",NOW())";
$result = mysql_query($sql) 
        or die("<p>Couldn't add character.<br/>".mysql_error()." in accounts.<br/>Please send this exact message to <a href='mailto:savvannis@houston-by-night.com'>Savvannis</a> with your character's name.</p>");
        echo $result;
echo $_SESSION['logname'];

$sql="INSERT INTO topdata (log_name,char_venue,sub_venue,species,char_name,create_date,gender,age,appage,nature,demeanor,concept,description,web_site,view_pword,sfa) VALUES (\"$_SESSION[logname]\",\"$_POST[char_venue]\",\"$_POST[sub_venue]\",\"$_POST[species]\",\"$_POST[char_name]\",NOW(),\"$_POST[gender]\",\"$_POST[age]\",\"$_POST[appage]\",\"$_POST[nature]\",\"$_POST[demeanor]\",\"$_POST[concept]\",\"$_POST[description]\",\"$_POST[web_site]\"\"$_POST[viewpw]\",\"$_POST[sfa]\")";
$result=mysql_query($sql)
       or die ("<p>Could not create character.<br/>".mysql_error()." in topdata.<br/>Please send this exact message to <a href='mailto:savvannis@houston-by-night.com'>Savvannis</a> with your character's name.</p>");
        echo $result;
```

When the information is entered into the form and submit is hit, I get the following:

```
1

Could not create character.
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 in topdata.
Please send this exact message to Savvannis with your character's name.
```

I look at the database and the information is entered into the accounts table, so that statement is working, but it is hanging up on the topdata table. It's not echoing the $_SESSION['logname'] and looking at the database, it's not saving the owner, which should be $_SESSION['logname'], so I'm wondering if that statement is now somehow incorrect??

I can't figure out what the heck is wrong.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hope this is more like a home work and not a real project. There is soo much that be improved in your code in terms of security, readability and good design patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a comma here: `\"$_POST[web_site]\"\"$_POST[viewpw]\"` in your second insert SQL.

It should be `\"$_POST[web_site]\", \"$_POST[viewpw]\"`

Answer (score 0):

First off the error message is telling you that there is an unequal number of columns and values in your SQL

Lets have a look at that

```
INSERT INTO topdata (
log_name,
char_venue,
sub_venue,
species,
char_name,
create_date,
gender,
age,
appage,
nature,
demeanor,
concept,
description,
web_site,
view_pword,
sfa
) VALUES (
\"$_SESSION[logname]\",
\"$_POST[char_venue]\",
\"$_POST[sub_venue]\",
\"$_POST[species]\",
\"$_POST[char_name]\",
NOW(),
\"$_POST[gender]\",
\"$_POST[age]\",
\"$_POST[appage]\",
\"$_POST[nature]\",
\"$_POST[demeanor]\",
\"$_POST[concept]\",
\"$_POST[description]\",
\"$_POST[web_site]\"\"$_POST[viewpw]\",
\"$_POST[sfa]\"
)";
```

Now by formatting your SQL (which is vulnerable to sql injection) I've noticed a missing comma between web_site and viewpw values

Comment: Sometimes it just takes an extra pair of eyes. Thank you.

Next issue is that the \"$_SESSION[logname]\" is not working, it's not saving the logged in user's name to the database....

You have to log into the site to get to the character sheet to input your character, and the character sheets begins with 

<?php
session_cache_expire(360);
session_start();
?>

Comment: And on the sheet it has a place that the $_SESSION['login'] is echoing properly, so I'm wondering what is going wrong on the insert statement??  Is there something I should be using instead of $_SESSION['login'] ??

Comment: @user3149907 - if you have a different problem, you might want to add a new question, rather than asking it in comments. But before you do - do some debugging. Is `$_SESSION['login']` being set? Have you started the session in this page?